# Url is not friendly - i18n

Tags: php, session, seo

I am using this code:

```
<ul>
   <a href="?lang=pt"><li class="pt lang"></li></a>
   <a href="?lang=en"><li class="us lang"></li></a>
</ul>
```

that will output an url link like this one:

```
http://localhost/site/?lang=en
```

My question is about SEO. SEO Doctor extension said this url is not friendly. How can i solve this? With sessions? How?

Something like this will work for me:

```
$_SESSION['lang']
```

Comment: Misread your question, sorry. You could add the language as your first parameter in your URL. something like `http://www.example.com/en/`

Comment: Most sites today use sub-site variations. For example: `http://www.example-domain.com/en-us/...` and `http://www.example-domain.com/fr-fr/...`

Comment: You can use a PHP framework for that. A really easy framework to work with is Codeigniter framework. There you can easily change the routes and have urls like this: http://www.example.com/en/blog, http://www.example.com/gr/blog ... e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the language in a session is for pure content pages not really user friendly - and at least not seo friendly, because you can have two url's with different content for each language.

It's better to store the language in the url - or use different domains to achieve this

```
example.com/site/    - for english content
example.de/site/     - for german content
```

or store the language in the url

```
example.com/de/site/
example.com/de/site/
```

an easy way to do this without changing the complete content is mod_rewrite and replacing `example.com/en/site/` with `example.com/site/` and add the `en` string to POST or GET params

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what HTTP server you're using. Assuming you're using Apache, you can create `clean URLs` by configuring the `mod_rewrite` extension in an appropriate .htaccess file.

For example, here's what [Drupal](http://drupal.org) is doing in its .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

You could use similar rules to pass the "lang" (and any other) parameters as parts of your URL. So, with appropriately configured rewrite rules, a URL like this:

```
http://something.com/?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3
```

could become:

```
http://something.com/1/2/3
```

which essentially assigns the first part of the URL to `foo`, the second to `bar` and the third to `baz`